# Spring Data Elasticsearch Geo Shape Type for Multipoint use

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

We are currently using spring data elastic search.  I would like to create a field that is of the type geo_shape so I can create a multipoint field with multiple coordinate geoJson points.  I see that the project supports a GeoPointFields but don't see Geo Shapes.

Is there a way to specify geo_shape?

If not, I see there is a custom mapping object.  Can we just specify in the template/mappings Geo Shape and use some custom entity to map what we need.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm also trying to use Spring Data Elasticsearch for Geo Shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this helps but what i did is build a class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
public static class GeoShape {
        String type;
        JsonNode coordinates;
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public JsonNode getCoordinates() {
            return coordinates;
        }

        public void setCoordinates(JsonNode coordinates) {
            this.coordinates = coordinates;
        }
    }
```

I have the geo shape mapping for elasticsearch and this works with spring data for saving/retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @m1416 is correct - but only works if you *just* use ES.

You'll find that if you try to use JPA/Hibernate *together* with ES, this doesn't work. Hibernate will complain that it can't convert values. And if you search for a converter class for json nodes, you'll find several classes that don't work or produce cryptic serialization errors in a post-commit rollback step.

I've been looking for many hours to find how to get this to work in a way that lets you search geographically via ES, without getting these serialization errors.

Here's a JsonNodeConverter that works:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonNodeConverter implements AttributeConverter<JsonNode, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(JsonNode jsonNode){
        if (jsonNode == null  || jsonNode.asText() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return jsonNode.asText();

    }

    @Override
    public JsonNode convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonNode = null;
        try {
            jsonNode = mapper.readTree(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonNode;
    }
}
```

To use this, do the following annotation on your JsonNode attribute of your entity:

```
@Column(name="geography", columnDefinition="LONGTEXT")
@Convert(converter=JsonNodeConverter.class)
private JsonNode geometry;
```